# Mongodb bulk write error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm executing bulk write

`bulk = new_packets.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()`

`bulk.insert(packet)`

`output = bulk.execute()`

and getting an error that I interpret to mean that packet is not a dict. However, I do know that it is a dict. What could be the problem?

Here is the error:

```
    BulkWriteError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-311-93f16dce5714> in <module>()
          2 
          3 bulk.insert(packet)
    ----> 4 output = bulk.execute()

    C:\Users\e306654\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.pyc in execute(self, write_concern)
583         if write_concern and not isinstance(write_concern, dict):
584             raise TypeError('write_concern must be an instance of dict')
    --> 585         return self.__bulk.execute(write_concern)

    C:\Users\e306654\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.pyc in execute(self, write_concern)
429             self.execute_no_results(generator)
430         elif client.max_wire_version > 1:
    --> 431             return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern)
432         else:
433             return self.execute_legacy(generator, write_concern)

    C:\Users\e306654\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.pyc in execute_command(self, generator, write_concern)
296                 full_result['writeErrors'].sort(
297                     key=lambda error: error['index'])
    --> 298             raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
299         return full_result
300 

    BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

Comment: what is packet? what is the output of `print(packet)`?

Comment: Ok, the problem was that i was assigning _id explicitly and it turns out that the string was larger than 12-byte limit, my bad.

Comment: PyMongo [acknowledges this is a common issue in their docs and offers insight](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#why-does-pymongo-add-an-id-field-to-all-of-my-documents) as to why this occurs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that i was assigning _id explicitly and it turns out that the string was larger than 12-byte limit, my bad.

Comment: wow, I faced exactly the same problem, thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 32):

It can be many reasons...
the best is that you try...catch... the exception and check in the errors

```
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
try:
    bulk.execute()
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(bwe.details)
    #you can also take this component and do more analysis
    #werrors = bwe.details['writeErrors']
    raise
```

Answer (score 17):

You should check 2 things:

1. Duplicates, if you are defining your own key.
2. Be able to manage custom types, In my case I was trying to pass a hash type object that was not able to be converted into a valid objectId, and that was leading me to the first point and I felt into a vicious circle (I solve it converting myObject to string.

Inserting one by one will give you the idea what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, check your `unique` `indexes`. If you're bulk inserting and have specified an index that doesn't exist in your data, you will get this error.

For example, I had accidentally specified `name` as a `unique` `index`, and the data I was inserting had no keys called `name`. After the first entry is inserted into mongo, it will throw this error because you're technically inserting another document with a `unique` `name` of `null`.

Here's a part of my model definition where I'm declaring a `unique` `index`:

```
self.conn[self.collection_name].create_index(
            [("name", ASCENDING)],
            unique=True,
        )
```

And here are the details of the error being thrown:

```
{'writeErrors': [{'index': 1, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'name': 1},
'keyValue': {'name': None}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:
troposphere.temp index: name_1 dup key: { name: null }'
...
```

more resources:
[MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988941/mongodb-e11000-duplicate-key-error)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to insert two documents with the same "_id" and other keys.
Solution:

1. insert different "_id" s for different documents. OR
2. remove the "_id" and you get a randomized one.

Comment: This is covered by [@Miguel Angel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349183/3025856) from seven years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try using debugger, it should gives you `errmsg` with exact error, and `op` object was trying to insert.