# Do bulk inserts/update in MongoDB with PyMongo

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

How do I bulk update/insert in mongoDb with pymongo/pandas. 
The error  I  get is `batch op errors occurred`
I reason I get is because I set the `"_id"`, which I want to do. I code runs fine on first run, but on second run it fails. I want to use pandas in workflow. The data does have a datetime object.

The syntax is completely different for `upsert = True`, with `Update`.  An efficient solution with `update` would be helpful, where `"_id"` or `"qid"` could be set.  **But,  there are python datetime objects!**

```
InSQL   = 'SELECT * from  database2.table2 '
sqlOut  = pd.read_sql(InSQL,cxn)
sqlOut['_id'] = "20170101" + ":"+ sqlOut['Var']   

dfOut   = sqlOut.to_json(orient='records',date_format='iso' )
try:
    db["test"].insert_many(json.loads(dfOut))
except Exception as e:  print e
```

I have given a **50**pt bounty, which expired, with no answer. Hmm...

Comment: Mongo used `string base input` and not allow any variable inserting(operator only)[check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object), `json.loads(dfOut)` you can't insert local variable as entry ! Primary key `YYYYmmDDHHMMSS`+`Counter value`

Comment: You can dig into the `BulkWriteError` details and get a better idea of what's going on.  It may be that your personally defined ids are duplicated or violate the 12-byte limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355790/mongodb-bulk-write-error for details.

Comment: The fact that the _id worked the first time, tells me that 12-byte limit is not the concern. Yes, the _id or gid are dups and needed for update.

Comment: It sounds like your goal is to do an upsert but the current sample code is doing an insert (so it is expected that the successive runs will fail with duplicate `_id` keys). Can you update with a short example of the `dfOut` content and the upsert code you tried? Also, what version of PyMongo are you using? I suspect you actually want to use `update_many()` with the `upsert` option set. Can you also clarify the concerns on Python datetime objects and `_id` versus `qid`? Do you want to use the `qid` as the `_id`?

Answer (score 8):

You get an error because you try to insert documents with fields which conflict with that of existing documents on the second and subsequent `insert_many` calls. You correctly inferred it may be due to your setting `_id` explicitly, which would then conflict with existing `_id` values in the collection.

MongoDB [automatically creates an *unique index* on `_id`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index), which forbids duplicating values.

You need to **update or replace** your documents on calls after the first one (which inserted the documents in their first version). There is indeed a concept of "upsert" which will take care of inserting non-previously-existing documents in the collection as well as updating the existing ones.

Your options:

- Most efficient: [`pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write)

  ```
  import pymongo

  operations = [pymongo.operations.ReplaceOne(
      filter={"_id": doc["_id"]}, 
      replacement=doc,
      upsert=True
      ) for doc in json.loads(dfOut)]

  result = db["test"].bulk_write(operations)
  # handle results
  ```

Note that it's efficiency also depends on whether the field is indexed in the collection, which incidentally is the case for `_id`.
(also see [`pymongo.operations.ReplaceOne`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.ReplaceOne))

- Loop over your collection and calling [`pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) or [`pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one)(inefficient because not bulk)

  ```
  import pymongo

  results = []
  for doc in json.load(dfOut):
      result = db["test"].replace_one(
          filter={"_id": doc["_id"]},
          replacement=doc,
          upsert=True
          )
      results.append(result)

  # handle results
  ```

Note: [`pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) seems unsuitable for your needs since you are not trying to set the same value on all matches of a given filter.

Answer (score 2):

batch op error maybe caused by duplicate _id,
 So delete the same _id documents already in mongo before inserting

Or use update_many
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/